# Python slowing down after int printed out reaches 1,000,000

Tags: python, printing, integer

I'm really new to Python, I'm just experimenting with code and i suddenly noticed something quite annoying.

```
# (mports
import random
import math
import time
import os
import sys
import csv

# Main

def clear():
    os.system("cls")

Population = 2

timetaken = 0

while True:

    timetaken += 1

    PossibleBirths = Population / 2

    PossibleBirths = int(PossibleBirths)

    for n in range(PossibleBirths):
        luck = random.randint(1, 100)

        if luck >= 75:
            Population += 1
        else:
            Population += 0
    
    print("Years: "+str(timetaken))
    print("Current Population: "+'{0:,.0f}'.format(Population))
    time.sleep(0.25)
    clear()
```

After like 100 years, or after it reaches around 1,000,000 it slows down printing really rapidly, often taking 5 seconds to just print out.

Any idea why?

After trying to increase/decrease the sleep time, i still haven't come to a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is not with printing, it comes from the for loop. The more your `Population` grows, the higher the `PossibleBirths` is. Since you're looping over `range(PossibleBirths)`, at each step you do more and more iteration in the for loop.

The solution here is "simple": replace the for loop by an equivalent probability function which statistically gives the same result.

If you're only interested in the average growth, then simply increase the population by `(1-0.75)*PossibleBirths`.

If you truly want something random, then use a [binomial law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: How would i do something like this?